# Why doesn't CssClass work when a regular class does?

Tags: asp.net, css

In my CSS file I have:

```
.Center
{
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then, when I have the following all is well:

```
<div class="Center">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="..." runat="server" />
</div>
```

But if I remove the `div` and add a `CssClass` instead - it ignores the class:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="..." runat="server" CssClass="Center" />
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried to see final markup that is rendered in browser? Does css class appear in it?

Comment: That would be the first step in debugging this. If the `img` element renders `class=center` then we can debug this further.

Comment: @Johnny_D I'm new to web developing so I didn't think of that. Anyway, I just checked, and it's rendered: <input name="ImageButton1" **class="Center"** id="ImageButton1" type="image" src="..."/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because an `asp:ImageButton` renders out as `<input type="image" ... />`. Your first example has a `<div>` wrapping the image button, and the styling is applied on the `<div>`. Your second example is attempting to style the `<input type="image" ... />` directly (which doesn't work because it's not a block element).

You can use an `<asp:Panel>` (which renders as a `<div>`) for equivalent code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="Center">
     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="..." runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Or, change your CSS to work with an `<input type="image">` - I think that's as easy as just adding `display: block`, and the other properties will work the same as a containing `<div>` would.